# Merge two DataFrames 1:1

Tags: python, pandas

I'd like to merge two DataFrams that contains two common columns. They have the same number of row and I know the order in both columns is the same, so they are already aligned.
My problem is that, after they've merged I'm left with more rows than I originally had.

Is there a way to merge these two DataFrames and keep the original number if rows?

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame(
   [
      {"col1": 1, "col2": 1, "unique_df1_val": "value1"},
      {"col1": 2, "col2": 2, "unique_df1_val": "value2"},
      {"col1": 2, "col2": 2, "unique_df1_val": "value3"},
   ]
)

df2 = pd.DataFrame(
   [
      {"col1": 1, "col2": 1, "unique_df2_val": "value4"},
      {"col1": 2, "col2": 2, "unique_df2_val": "value5"},
      {"col1": 2, "col2": 2, "unique_df2_val": "value6"},
   ]
)


### Do some merge of the two ###


# Expected DataFrame

    col1    col2    unique_df1_val  unique_df2_val
0   1       1       value1          value4
1   2       2       value2          value5
2   2       2       value3          value6
```

I've tried using the df1.merge(df2, how="outer"), but this doesn't give me the correct output.

```
df1.merge(df2, how="outer")
# Returns

    col1    col2    unique_df1_val  unique_df2_val
0   1       1       value1          value4
1   2       2       value2          value5
2   2       2       value2          value6
3   2       2       value3          value5
4   2       2       value3          value6
```

Comment: If you look closely, col1 doesn't have a 3 as a third value, instead a 2. Either your input data is wrong, or what you are trying to achieve is impossible (as in create a 3)

Comment: That was a typo, thanks for noticing!

Comment: Does order matter? If you move row 2 of `df2` in the last position, should the output be the same or should value3 go with value4?

Comment: They are sorted and aligned so that row 1 in df1 and df2 are connected and so on for each row

Comment: Then use `df1['unique_df2_val'] = df2['unique_df2_val']` ;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If they are all equally in length and previously sorted, with the same number of observations per col1 and col2, consider using [join](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.join.html) instead of merge. However be cautious since the operation is on indexes (by default), rather than column values:

> Join columns with other DataFrame either on index or on a key column. Efficiently join multiple DataFrame objects by index at once by passing a list.

```
df1.join(df2,lsuffix='drop').drop(columns=[x+'drop' for x in df1.columns if x in df2.columns])
```

Output:

```
  unique_df1_val  col1  col2 unique_df2_val
0         value1     1     1         value4
1         value2     2     2         value5
2         value3     2     2         value6
```

If a merge operation is not needed because the data will always be perfectly aligned, then just consider defining the new column:

```
df1['unique_df2_val'] = df2['unique_df2_val']
```

Comment: This is not really a `merge`, this assumes that the rows are already aligned (in which case a simple concat or assignment would be better)

Comment: The latter option did also work, on second try :D

Answer (score 2):

Use [`pd.concat`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.concat.html) instead of `merge`. If you have your data aligned, you could just concatenate the column/columns you want in the final of the dataframe.

```
pd.concat([df1, df2['unique_df2_val']], axis=1)
```

Output:

```
    col1    col2    unique_df1_val  unique_df2_val
0   1         1        value1          value4
1   2         2        value2          value5
2   2         2        value3          value6
```

Answer (score 2):

For an efficient solution and a **real merge**, deduplicate before the [`merge`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.merge.html):

```
cols = ['col1', 'col2']

out = (df1.merge(df2, left_on=[df1.groupby(cols).cumcount(), *cols],
                     right_on=[df1.groupby(cols).cumcount(), *cols])
          .drop(columns='key_0')
      )
```

Output:

```
   col1  col2 unique_df1_val unique_df2_val
0     1     1         value1         value4
1     2     2         value2         value5
2     2     2         value3         value6
```

Comment: Beat me to it. Additional explanation: what's deduplicated here is each combination of col1 and col2 by introducting a third column that keeps count of these duplicates.